# Plotting Differential equation x(t) vs t

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

I have the system equations as

```
x'[t] == x[t]*(1 - x[t]^2 - y^2) - y*(1.1 - y/(x[t]^2 + y^2)^(1/2))
```

I am trying to solve and plot the equation by using

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
x[t]*(1 - x[t]^2 - y^2) - y*(1.1 - y/(x[t]^2 + y^2)^(1/2)), 
x[t] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

and

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x'[t] /. sol1}], {t, 0, 100}]
```

but I keep getting errors. And I do not understand why. This is what I should be plotting [image]

Comment: What is `y`? Your initial condition should be something like `x[0] == 0`, not `x[t] == 0`.

Comment: I am assuming y is a variable that may or may not vary with t. The plot I included is a plot of x(t) vs t.

Comment: `y` needs to be defined in some way, or you'll get the `non-numerical value` error from `NDSolve`. Also, you're solving for `x[t]` up to `t == 10`, but trying to plot it up to `t == 100`.

Comment: If `y` is not a number, then you will need to use `DSolve`. `NDSolve` only works with numerical equations.

Comment: The plot you provide has to correspond to a particular value of `y`. Moreover,  from the plot `x[0]` is not `0`, and should be given.

Comment: Further, you wanted to plot `x[t]`not `x'[t]`, as `NDsolve` provides the first.

Comment: Can you share any link or something from where we can see a little detail about this plot?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, in numeric computations, where possible, avoid using numbers with limited precision like yours `1.1` - replace by exact `1/10`. Secondly, as many folks suggested in comments, you should pass to numerical functions such as `NDSolve` (N - is for numeric) things that are defined. So your comment:

> I am assuming y is a variable that may or may not vary with t.

will not make it tractable by `NDSolve`. If you do not believe me you can [**check with Boromir**](https://i.imgflip.com/1yo6oo.jpg) ;-) The only way I can possibly reconcile "may or may not vary with t" is if y is a "weak" function of t depending on a small parameter. If that parameter goes to zero then y becomes a constant. Then you might experiment with your setup a bit trying different y-behaviors. Define a general function:

```
eq[y_] := x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]^2 - y^2) - y (11/10 - y/(x[t]^2 + y^2)^(1/2))
```

In simplest case

```
eq[0]
```

[image]

you have nice analytic solution

```
DSolve[{eq[0], x[0] == a}, x, t]
```

[image]

which BTW is not periodic - a thing to notice. So you can experiment with more general forms of y. Not all forms will be integrable. I do not know your form of y so I pick any - replace at your will.

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[{#,D[#,t]}//Evaluate,
    {t,0,fi},PlotRange->All,Filling->Axis,
    PlotTheme->"Detailed",PlotLegends->{x[t],x'[t]}]&@
    NDSolveValue[
            {eq[a+b Sin[2t]],x[0]==x0},
            x,{t,0,fi}][t],
{{a,1/10},-2,2,Appearance->"Labeled"},
{{b,1/10},-1,1,Appearance->"Labeled"},
{{x0,1/10},-2,2,Appearance->"Labeled"},
{{fi,20},1,20,Appearance->"Labeled"}]
```

[image]